# how to program Virtual PC 2007 to automate tasks?

Tags: c#, com, virtual-machine

I have virtual machine that has windows 7 + visual studio 2010 setup, and my plan is to test some VS SDK development. Now I want to automate following tasks...

1. Detach existing VHD
2. Delete VHD
3. Create a new Differencing VHD with base VHD as already good setup
4. Attach it to the VM
5. Start VM

I tried to look for any OCX or COM control to do these tasks automatically but no luck, I didn't find any COM library to do this.

However, if I can only delete and recreate a differencing VHD that also should be fine..., I know I can write to batch file to copy a backup of new VHD and do all these kinds of things, but I am looking for much more sophesticated solution where I can program in scripts and do more with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [extensive automation interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd796758%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Virtual Server, but not for Virtual PC.  I don't have it installed on my machine to help you find it.  But you can probably find it yourself.  Fire up regedit.exe and navigate through HKCR.  There should be a ProgId named some similar to "VirtualMachine.Application".  Note the CLSID guid.  Navigate to `HKCR\CLSID\{guid}` and note the InProcServer32 key value.  That should be the DLL that you can browse to in the Browse tab of the Add Reference dialog.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, this is what exactly I am looking for but can you tell me from where I can get TLB or how to I get everything in C#?

Comment: Well the msdn help specifies GUID and interface information, I have to actually type everything in order to get into C#, but I want to know how can I import any DLL that will generate C# interfaces.

Comment: I found typelib GUID that is "{CEF63746-AD34-42D0-9138-39D83ECB77CB}" after going in regedit, and tried navigating couple of guids mentioned there and in msdn, but no luck, you cant find dll easily for windows components, i remember, even for directshow there was none and somebody created project in sourceforge that had all interfaces documented, its quite painful job, however it says in windows SDK i can find tlb, let me try downloading that.

Comment: I downloaded and installed it, no dice.  Then found a feature comparison, the scripting interface is only available for Virtual Server, not Virtual PC.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8ed0a6cb-0f24-408e-af8f-51edf508d361